# Does Reason support nullable types?

Tags: null, nullable, reason

This is a newbie question, but I couldn't find a quick answer anywhere.

Does Facebook's Reason language support nullable types? If so, in what form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `null`. The closest we have is option variant. See various documentation below:

https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/newcomer-examples.html#using-the-option-type
https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/variant.html#option

Let me know if there is a specific kind of situation that you would have a `null` in JavaScript that you would like to see the Reason equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Neil, Reason itself has [the `option` type](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/variant.html#option). However, if you have to deal with possible `null` or `undefined` values from JavaScript, there's also [`Js.Nullable.t`](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/null-undefined-option.html). It can be converted to an `option` when needed using [`Js.toOption`](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.html#VALtoOption).

There are also more specific types that only handle either `null` or `undefined` but the other, [`Js.Null.t`](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Null.html) and [`Js.Undefined.t`](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Undefined.html) respectively, but you'll rarely if ever need these. I mention them just for the sake of completeness.